# How is the order of champion pick selected (draft pick)?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know in ranked games, a characters [elo](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Elo_rating_system) determines the order of champion picks.  In non-ranked [draft pick](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Draft_Pick), pre-arranged teams have priority.  Does team size, elo, or anything else affect the order of champion pick?

Comment: This question is no longer relevant, as Riot has changed the way pick order works.  The player who gets to ban is selected randomly, but team captains (those who invite others) absorb their players chance to be picked.  Ex: If 5 singles are matched, each has a 20% chance to ban.  If a 3 man premade team is matched with 2 singles, each single has a 20% chance to ban, but the captain of the premade has a 60% chance (and those he invited have 0% chance).
http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Draft_Pick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the ranking only considers premade teams vs. solo queuers.  Premades get higher priority (order randomized within the team), then any stragglers get randomly thrown in underneath them.  This is why you end up in the bottom 1 to 2 slots so often if you solo queue for normal draft pick games - you're getting matched up with a pre-made (or 2).

I don't think that there's been any official word from Riot on this though, so this is all conjecture.

Comment: There's an actual post I remember reading, but can't seem to find, that does confirm the information. Elo, however, was removed from non-ranked games.

Answer (score 4):

Pick order is random now in draft/rank mode. This was done, I think, so people can't easily recognize duo queues and get upset before the game (obviously riot doesn't say this officially).

The randomness does have some non-random aspects though. If you are duo/group queueing, the captain of the team will get swapped in for first pick(and banner) if any of the team is randomly put in that first spot and they will replace the captain in whatever spot he is in.